# Probabilistic Analog to Digital Convertion

Tags: analog, adc, digital-modulation

I was listening to a talk where the speaker mentioned a couple of ways to represent an analog signal with a digital signal. He mentioned the typical ones like:

1. Encoding the analog value in terms of the duration of the digital pulse.
2. Doing something like a sigma-delta modulator, where the average of the pulses is the analog value.

I'm familiar with these techniques. Then he mentioned another technique which I haven't heard of. He said another method is to generate a random digital signal in which the probability of getting a 1 corresponds to the analog value. Can anyone direct me to what exactly he is talking about.

Comment: Chad it’s a research only method of nanosecond magnetic transistor memory that toggles with hysteresis and noise by integrating the applied voltage.  It’s easy to find a slideshow on this topic, but it’s not a commercial part nor easy to understand.  ... the benefits don’t exist yet. Maybe in 10 years. Because it’s been in research for at least 20 yrs. Due to noise , thousands of samples are needed. ... To probably get an accurate result. Expected from 8 bit resolution.

Comment: Was the technique mentioned perhaps [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems something like [pulse density modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/pulse-density_modulation) to me. Somewhat of a mixup from a sigma delta converter and the bitstream from an LFSR maybe?

No idea of how that would be useful. Maybe it would have useful spectral properties.